# What special method in Python handles AttributeError?

Tags: python, attributeerror

What special method(s?) should I redefine in my class so that it handled `AttributeError`s exceptions and returned a special value in those cases?

For example,

```
>>> class MySpecialObject(AttributeErrorHandlingClass):
      a = 5
      b = 9
      pass
>>>
>>> obj = MySpecialObject()
>>>
>>> obj.nonexistent
'special value'
>>> obj.a
5
>>> obj.b
9
```

I googled for the answer but couldn't find it.

Comment: Note that `pass` here is unnecessary.

Comment: The attributed `a` and `b` are class attributes you are accessing on the instance `obj`. There is nothing wrong with that, but it is unusual. Do you understand how to define instance attributes?

Comment: @voyager, In your edit, you invented `AttributeErrorHandlingClass` as the mechanism for acquiring fallback attribute values. This is probably not the right way to gain this behavior in a particular class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would simply define all the other attributes and—if one is missing—Python will fall back on `__getattr__`.

Example:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "hi"
        self.bar = "mom"

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return "hello world"

c = C()
print c.foo # hi
print c.bar # mom 
print c.baz # hello world
print c.qux # hello world
```

Answer (score 3):

You have do override `__getattr__`, it works like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 'bar'

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
          return 'special value'

foo = Foo()
foo.bar # calls Foo.__getattribute__() (defined by object), returns bar
foo.baz # calls Foo.__getattribute__(), throws AttributeError, 
        # then calls Foo.__getattr__() which returns 'special value'.
```

Comment: Thanks for telling about the gotchas! Before I read your full answer, I did this: class Foo(object): def __init__(self): self.attrx = 'valx' ... def __getattr__(self, attr): return 'special value'  and it somehow worked! Should it or should it not really work?

Comment: By "somehow worked" I mean when i accessed `foo_obj.attrx` it returned `valx`, but when I accessed `foo_obj.nonexist` it returned 'special value'.

Comment: That is not a proper use of `__getattr__` at all. `__getattr__`, as opposed to `__getattribute__` operates as a fallback method if the meaningful attributes are already defined, so you don't have to look up normal attributes in `__getattr__`.

Comment: @Bodacydo: true, the gotcha I described doesn't apply to your case. First __getattribute__() is called, when that throws an exception, `__getattr__()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear to me, but it sounds like you are looking for `__getattr__` and possibly for `__setattr__`, and `__delattr__`.

Comment: Oh. What I want to do is when the object doesn't have the given property, it returns special value.

For example, given that `obj` has the property `a` writing `obj.a` returns the value of `a`. But when `obj` doesn't have a property, like `nosuch` then writing `obj.nosuch` returns value `special value`.

Does this explanation make sense?